# delete row from database and gridview c#

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, row

I've made my first sql table viewer. I would like to know how to delete and how to add rows to the database using `datagridview` and `c#`. I've found some sample code but they specify the tables for me I want to be valid for any table in database. Could you please help me?

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows) {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help people to help you if you were to post the code you were trying, and reference which sites you had looked at. Why not just try some code based on what you have found and see, and then ask for help refining it ...

Comment: Well I've found this code, but i don't know how to use it and if it update database

Comment: Well, what do the manual pages for the methods say?